# SuperUser renders oddly in Firefox, truncating question titles

Tags: support

I came to SuperUser.SE for the first time today and this site, unlike all the other SE sites I've used, renders unhelpfully for me in Firefox:

[image: This site in Firefox 3.0.19]

As you can see, I have turned off Stylish and Greasemonkey and there is no blocked Javascript.  The site renders fine in IE 7 (which I generally don't use).  It might render fine in a newer version of Firefox; I haven't tried.

I'm not a CSS expert.  (That's an understatement.)  Can anybody tell me what's going on with the indent and the truncated titles and what I might be able to do about it?  (I'm accessing the site from a corporate network with rules about software; upgrading versions isn't trivial.)

Comment: It looks like you have things zoomed in very far. What happens when you load the site on normal zoom (Ctrl+0)?

Comment: Oh, I see.  In order to get the text on the question pages in a size I can read I had to zoom that far.  Two notches out gets me the normal, working layout on the main page (yay), but question pages that are too small for me.  Maybe there's something I can plug into Stylish to fix the question pages?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what to tell you there.  Perhaps you could add a setting to increase the size of the titles without increasing the size of everything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @nhinkle for pointing me in the right direction in comments.  Rather than try to fix the main page, I added the following Stylish script to get the question pages up to a size I could read:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("http://superuser.com/questions"),
               url-prefix("http://superuser.com/questions") {
    body{
        font-size: 11pt !important;
    }

}
```

I pattern-matched this based on customizations in the Save Your Eyes Stylish style (published with the Mozilla add-on some time back).  Actually, I just added it to my copy. :-)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't you using Firefox's native zoom capabilities? They scale everything together, not just text, so the layout (of every website) is preserved correctly.

Comment: @DMA57361: If by native zoom you mean ctrl-+, I am using that.  The problem is that it remembers a zoom level per site, but the front page and questions pages use different font sizes, so the zoom level that works for one doesn't work for the other.

Comment: Oh, one other thing: if I were to zoom entire pages preserving layout, they're going to get too wide and require horizontal scrolling, which is a usability barrier.

Comment: Fair enough. Just thinking aloud, but are you aware Firefox can enforce a minimum font size for all pages? Accessed [like so](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zcyFj.png) in FF6.

Comment: Oddly, I'm already specifying a minimum font size, but it's not always being honored (including here).  I haven't tried to dig into it.  (Hmm, where would it be appropriate to ask Firefox questions? :-) )

Comment: Firefox questions? They go right here, on the main [main] site :)